# How to change my arrows on wordpress theme? And clickable image

Tags: html, css, wordpress, customization, elementor

I am setting up WordPress site and I have problem with one element from the CSS file and don't know how to fix it.

My problem is with these two arrows (left and right carets):

[image: My problem is with theese two arrows.]

Here is link of this website: www.mojatezga.me

I want to separate arrows from my elements and how could I make the icons clickable?

Sincerly,
TezgaMe

Comment: Were you able to fix this?  I don't see that issue on your website.

Comment: @KevinMarsden Yes i fixed it, my css thing didint loaded it in real time :)